# How to create tokens in django rest framework for users registered through J2EE website?

Tags: android, django, authentication, servlets, django-rest-framework

I have a website built using jsp and servlets on which a user can register.
The same user can login(not register) through an android app for which i have built a rest api in django rest framework. I am using token authentication. I am confused about how to create a token for the user when he registers on the website, since the token will be created by DRF but a new user will created through servlets. Is it possible what i am trying to do? Please can someone explain how to create tokens for new users in this case?

Update-
The token for the superuser is created automatically. For every other user that registers through the website tokens are created when i run the following script in the python shell

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token

for user in User.objects.all():
    Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
```

Isn't there any way such that this script runs every time data is inserted in the auth_user table?

I also put the following method in models.py, but it does not seem to work.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Token.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Update- So i tried everything i could thing of to automatically create tokens when a user registers but seems like create_auth_token cannot detect it. I am sure there is something that is missing, but cant figure out what. So i am manually creating tokens in java servlet using this code

```
final String rand = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
            Random rnd = new Random();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( 20 );
            for( int i = 0; i < 20; i++ ) 
            {
                sb.append( rand.charAt( rnd.nextInt(rand.length()) ) );
            }
            String key = sb.toString();

            char[] chars = key.toCharArray();
            StringBuffer hex = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++)
            {
                hex.append(Integer.toHexString((int) chars[i]));
            }
            key = hex.toString();

            query = new String("insert into authtoken_token(key, created, user_id) values ('"+key+"',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,(SELECT id FROM Auth_User WHERE username='"+loginid+"'))");
            st.executeUpdate(query);
```

This seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to the database which seems likely since you can register a user through the J2EE website, you should also be able to insert a token in the database too.
The table is made of 3 fields:

- `key` is a 40 random hexadecimal string (representing 20 chars),
- `user` a foreign key to the user's id,
- `created` the creation date.

Comment: Thank u for your reply. Yes, i have access to the database. Whenever a user registers his data is inserted in the table, i have also made a custom user for DRF. But how do i create a token automatically whenever a user registers through the website?

Comment: How do you create the user ?If it's by inserting directly the data in database, you can also do a second insertion for the token. The table name is `authtoken_token` and the structure is described in the answer above.

Comment: What about the key? Do i just create a random string for every user that registers in the servlet?

Comment: It's a random 40 chars long hexadecimal string (i.e. 0 to 9 and a to f). Examples: "c7d5501ebbf5316368da9226d24e11e8644c1bc2" or "b1533352468442fc3cb96ff4a53e15cdfebec9de"

Comment: I meant to say creating a token myself will work? Beacuse i thought token creation is done by DRF. I will try this out and mark the answer correct. Thank you.

Comment: Auth token is done by DRF but it's still a random string. Reference being the implementation: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/authtoken/models.py#L38